# How to perform a Login unsing HttpPost method. What Parameters Do I have to send in the Post, and how can I Get the response

Tags: java, http-post, apache-commons

I need to provide a simple Login using HttpClient via HttpPost method. This is what I have:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

String url = "http://10.20.128.47/ilias/ilias.php?lang=de&amp;client_id=0001&amp;cmd=post&amp;cmdClass=ilstartupgui&amp;cmdNode=jt&amp;baseClass=ilStartUpGUI&amp;rtoken=";

List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "client01"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "client01"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

it doesn't seem to work. I am using the "action=" - url from the html code on that login page. I can do A HttpGet without problems.

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = "";

while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

this gives me the login page that I want.
So I want to perform the HttpPost method which will log me in and then I want to do a HttpGet which gives me the http code of the logged in user. Can anybody help me please?
What am I doing wrong?
Thanx

Comment: I would recommend tracing the flow of calls to the server using something like Chrome Developer Tools. With the tools open/running, login to the server using a regular web page, and monitor the actual call that needs to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you forget to call

*response = httpclient .execute(httppost);*